# Looping inside non constant Data swift

Tags: swift, loops, foreach

```
I want to make my own pagination  system 
I have an issue looping thru non-constant elements.
```

I would like to add to the paginated data list only the elements of the initial list that are not already present and below the next pagination step.

I get the error of looping thru nonconstant elements or, if I try to get the index, the func: handle pagination doesn't conform to view

```
 import SwiftUI


  var   dataModel1 :DataModel = .init()
  var   dataModel2 :DataModel = .init()
  var   dataModel3 :DataModel = .init()
  var   dataModel4 :DataModel = .init()


  class DataModel: ObservableObject  {
      
      
      var id: String
      var name: String

      public   init() {
          
          self.name = "VOID"
          self.id = UUID().description
          
      }
      
  }

  class DataListOO : ObservableObject {
      
      @Published var dataList = [DataModel]()
      
    
  }



  struct SwipeCellDemoView: View {
      
      
      @ObservedObject var data3 = DataListOO()
      @ObservedObject var paginatedData = DataListOO()
      
      
      
      @State private var index: Int = 0
      @State private var deleted: Bool = false
      @State private var dragCompleted: Bool = false
      @State private var numberElementsLoaded: Int = 6
      @State private var maxElementVisibleIndex: Int = 0
      @State private var numberOfPaginations : Int = 1
      @State private var isLoading : Bool = false
      
      @State private var shortList : Bool = true
      @State private var loading : String = "NOT"
      @State private var i : Int = 0
      
      
      init(){
          
          
          dataModel1.name = "1111"
          dataModel2.name = "222"
          dataModel3.name = "3333"
          dataModel4.name = "44444"
       
        
          
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel1)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel1)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel1)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel1)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel1)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel1)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel1)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel1)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel2)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel3)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel3)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel3)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel3)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel3)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel3)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel3)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel4)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel4)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel4)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel4)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel4)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel4)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel4)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel4)
          data3.dataList.append(dataModel4)
          
          
          for i in 0..<6 {
              paginatedData.dataList.append(data3.dataList[i])
          }
       
          
      }
      
      var body: some View {
          
          Text(loading)
          
          VStack(){
            
              ScrollView(.vertical,showsIndicators: false){
                  
                  ScrollViewReader { value in
                      
                      LazyVStack (alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: 0){
                          
                          ForEach(paginatedData.dataList.indices) { i in
                              
                              HStack(spacing: 16) {

                                  VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                      
                                      Text(verbatim: paginatedData.dataList[i].name)
                                        
                                  }.onTapGesture {
                                      
                                  }
                              }
                              .padding()
                              .frame(width:400,height: 160)
                              
                              .onAppear(){
                            
                                  handlePagination(i)
                                  
                              }
                          }
                      }
                    
                  }
              }.disabled(isLoading)
              Spacer()
          }
          
         
          
          
      }
      
      
   
      
      //reset number pagination if research and if remove elements
      
      
      private func handlePagination(_ index : Int){
          
          if ( maxElementVisibleIndex < index ) {
              
              maxElementVisibleIndex = index
          }
         
       /* this is where I have the issue looping thru non-constant elements
      


          if (maxElementVisibleIndex == numberOfPaginations * Global.mainPaginationValue - 1)
          {
              
              ForEach(data3.dataList, id: \.id) { data in
                  
                  i =  data3.dataList.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == data.id })!
                  
                  /*
                   
                   if (i > numberElementsLoaded - 1 && i < numberElementsLoaded + Global.mainPaginationValue ){
              
                   
                   
                   paginatedData.dataList.append(data3.dataList[i])
                   
                   }
                   */
                  
              }
              
              
              
          }
          
          */
          
          
         numberOfPaginations = numberOfPaginations + 1
          numberElementsLoaded = numberElementsLoaded + Global.mainPaginationValue
             
          
          isLoading = true
          loading = "LOADING"
        
           DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3){
           isLoading = false
           loading = "NOT"
           print(loading)
           }
           
          
          
      }
      
  }
```

I get the error of looping thru nonconstant elements or , if I try to get the index, the function : handle pagination doesn't conform to view
The issue is here above where the right elements of the initial list must be added

Comment: Can you add a [mre]? It's really tough to tell what's going on from a bunch of lines of code that don't compile interspersed with other commentary.

Comment: ok , i will edit the question with a quite long piece of code , thank you

Comment: if you begin and end each block of code in your question with three back-ticks (\`\`\`) it will preserve the formatting of the code which help others answer your question.

Comment: Even without the code formatting I can see the line `let i = ...`.  If that is in a method or property that is returning `some View` you will need to add an explicit `return` statement for the `View` you're creating in that block of code.  It's a similar thing when you have a. simple closure you can just say the thing you're returning, but if you add more complexity you have to add `return` statements.

Comment: Thank you Jarred . I have to say i don t even understand how and why it must return something or has to conform to view Protocol . All i want is some values in a list .

Comment: You're trying to use the SwiftUI `ForEach`, which is for `View` code -- what you want on that line is `data3.dataList.forEach { data in`

Comment: Thank you for your help . Ive updated .forEach and i still have the error : ForEach should be used for constant data .Instead conform data to didentifiable or use ForEach() with id . I didn t know .forEach but i m asked to use ForEach() by Xcode

Comment: That’s a separate issue — you have two `ForEach`s in your code. That error you've just referred to relates to the one in your `View` code. It’s a result of using `ForEach` with `indices` and without an `id`.

Comment: ok; now i see the separate issue . I m still not able to add an index that Xcode accepts but im working on it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer based on JArred and Jnpdx help :
For non View related loops , for non constant lists , use : list.forEach{ element in

to loop the list . Once this is done, it is possible to retrieve the index of the elements you want to add (for pagination for example , you can not work with value, just position)

For View related loops : ForEach{   Index isn t mandatory but in case of changing lists , it must be added . As a consequence, you again retrieve the value of the list element and not its position .

If someone has some elements to add to this answer, he is welcomed .